# Show that if $(\sigma^r)^i$ is an $n$-cycle, then $\sigma^r$ is an $n$-cycle

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

I'm trying to show that if the power of $\sigma$ is an $n$-cycle, then $\sigma$ itself is an $n$-cycle. This seems to be something that is privy to a proof by contradiction but I can't seem to see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sigma = (123)(45)$. Then $\sigma^2 = (132)$ is a $3$-cycle but $\sigma$ is not a $3$-cycle.

Comment: @hardmath I made it an answer, assuming I have correctly understood the question.

Comment: It's a good example because it addresses some more general interpretations of the Question also (because $\sigma$ is no kind of cycle).

Answer (score 1):

[The original version stated](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2431076/1) that $\sigma$ is *a cycle* and $\sigma^i$ *an $n$-cycle*. The way I read it is that the task was to prove that the lengths of those two cycles must match. If we don't know that $\sigma$ is a cycle (the question was edited to read this way), then the claim is false. See Zoe's answer for a counterexample.

---

(Hints/answer to the original version)

If $\sigma$ is an $m$-cycle, then the $m$ objects moved by $\sigma$ are not mapped to themselves by any power $\sigma^i, 0<i<m$. Therefore $\sigma^i$ cannot be a shorter cycle (because it moves all those $m$ objects). However, it can be a product of several disjoint shorter cycles.

Comment: Trying to leave a suitable amount of details to be justified by the OP:

Comment: But we don't know that $\sigma$ is an $n$ cycle, only that$\sigma^i$ is

Comment: The way I read your question is that we know $\sigma$ to be a cycle of some unknown length $m$. Possible longer than $n$, i.e. $m>n$. The case $m<n$ is easier.

Comment: We don't know that. We just know that $\sigma^i$ is an m cycle and that $i$ and $m$ are co prime.